# Recommended approach to integrate GeoNetwork with SQL Server database

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, sql-server, metadata, geonetwork, catalog-service

I am new to GeoNetwork. But now my organization wants to invest in it to see how we can make the best use of it for publishing, sharing and distributing metadata.

We currently have all our GIS data (mostly feature classes) stored in ArcSDE databases on SQL Server 2008 R2. Only brief information about the data has been captured, therefore no standardization has been pursued.

My question is if we get a GeoNetwork catalogue set up, what is the best way to integrate it with the existing SQL Server databases. Also how does each metadata record in GeoNetwork get associated with the actual dataset in SQL Server? Can we set up GeoNetwork for it to automatically extract simple metadata of our specified from the SQL Server and push it to the GeoNetwork catalogue?

Comment: In ArcCatalog we can setup a geometric network using existing line/point layers and data of this geometric network is stored in SDE repository tables in the same geoDB.so any GNetwork we setup in a geodatabase using ArcCatalog,is implicity integrated with the feature classes(layers) that share in that GNetwork in one geoDatabase.Hope I've undestand the problem well.

Comment: Sorry Reza, we probably talked about different things. The GeoNetwork I was talking about is an opensource spatial data catalogueing system for metadata. See: http://geonetwork-opensource.org

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need to connect directly to the database?

You can use the harvest from ArcSDE:
http://geonetwork-opensource.org/manuals/trunk/eng/users/managing_metadata/harvesting/sde/index.html